# Convert PHP website to an HTML-based website

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess

I recently started working in a company and one of the first tasks that I was given was to redo their website.
Being a newbie and after a few trial and errors on sites like wix.com, weebly.com, I made a WordPress website with a responsive theme using a [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) server.

The site seems all fine but when the time came to finally put it on the server, I came to know that the hosting company only supports HTML based website whereas the website I built is a PHP one. The following are my questions

1. How do I go about publishing my WordPress site on an HTML supported only server? Is there a way to convert the website or any other method? If yes, please explain in detail as I am a newbie.
2. I was somehow able to export my database from the localhost MySQL server to that of the server where I want my site to be but does the web hosting company only supporting HTML based website affect the database in MySQL server? If yes, what should be done and how? Kindly explain in detail.

The [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel) of the webhost is pretty basic and on calling the company, I was told that all I had to do was drag and drop my files there for my site to go online but that dint work.

I tried changing the extensions from PHP to HTML and uploading the files, but all I get is a blank screen on going on going to www.mycompanydomain.ae.

I even tried the whole adding a line in the .htaccess file to open as an HTML without actually changing the all the PHP files but to no avail.
Kindly help as I have spent a lot of time and energy on this but now I am at a roadblock.

Comment: "I came to know that the hosting company only supports HTML based website" - *Really?* I find that hard to believe. Chances are then, they don't even PHPMyAdmin then huh?

Comment: If you need PHP but your webhost does not support (lolwut?), switch a webhost. There are thousands of free ones out there...

Comment: They do have a PHPMyAdmin,but supposedly its just for show as it is outdated and on calling the customer care of the company, I get 2 standard replies "Talk to a local technician, we cant help you with it" or "Sorry, we are not authorized to tell you that"

Comment: Also the company is getting the webhosting free with their telephone and internet account, so they dont really want to move from it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could browse through each page that makes up your website and use your browser to "save" a local copy of the page and upload these. A an easier way to accomplish this foolish task would be to use a web crawling tool like WebReaper on your local website and upload the results to the HTML only host.

The caveats to doing this are:

- Your site is no longer interactive, everything is static.
- Nice folder structure goes out the window and everything is a mess
- It's obviously a bad idea
- Don't do this, it's a bad idea
- No, seriously.

The correct solution, if you need to have anything server-side/database interactive, is switch to a host that has PHP enabled. You would also want to use a tool like PHPMyAdmin to export your local database and import it on the new host.

Comment: Wordpress stores the URLs in the database so you'll need to run a tool like [DATABASE SEARCH AND REPLACE SCRIPT IN PHP](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) after you've imported it as described above

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in HTML. But you can use [`iframe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framing_(World_Wide_Web)#Syntax) and wordpress.com or host it elsewhere...

Comment: And for a cheap and good host, try bluehost...

Comment: @ardaozkal If I get a new host like Bluehost, will I be able to use the domain name which I already have or will I have to use the one which they may provide?

Comment: @swati yes you can use the old one, contact both hosts to get more info

Comment: @ardaozkal is this legit? http://www.top10bestwebsitehosting.com/   can i rely on this ranking to think about changing my host?

Comment: @swati you can trust bluehost, it's cheap (5$) and it comes with a great performance...

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [Really Static/](http://wordpress.org/plugins/really-static/) claims to generate HTML files each time you update your WordPress blog: **"saving static files via local, FTP, SFTP"** and **"
if you don't have PHP/MySQL support on your server you can host your WordPress installation locally and use a normal HTML webspace for publishing"**

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

No, there's no practical way to transform your entire site into HTML.

Switch to a web host that supports PHP.

Comment: That answer is very subjective